# How to Choose the Preferred (but Specific) Regex Match Over a Default (but Universal) One?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to capture various parts of a text block, including whether it has a beginning or ending quotation mark and then the text block itself, excluding those quotation marks.  The Regex pattern works fine when I have either just an ending quote, both a period and ending quote or just an ending quote.

```
        string test = @"""This has a begin quote, period and end quote.""" + Environment.NewLine +
                      @"""This has a begin quote and period." + Environment.NewLine +
                      @"""This has a begin quote and end quote""" + Environment.NewLine +
                      @"""This has a begin quote only" + Environment.NewLine;

        string pattern = @"^\s*(?<BeginQuote>"")?" +
            @"(?<BodyPattern>.+((\.(?=""?\s*$))|(?=""\s*$)))" +
            @"(?<EndQuote>""(?=\s*$))?";

        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(test);

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            GroupCollection groups = m.Groups;
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning Quotation Mark:  {0}", groups["BeginQuote"].Success);
            Console.WriteLine("BodyPattern:  {0}", groups["BodyPattern"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Ending Quotation Mark:  {0}", groups["EndQuote"].Success);
        }
```

Here is the output:
Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote, period and end quote.
Ending Quotation Mark:  True

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote and period.
Ending Quotation Mark:  False

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote and end quote
Ending Quotation Mark:  True

The problem is when I try to provide a match for the case in which there is neither an ending quote or a period.  I have tried multiple variations to catch the end of string.  This always works, but ends up capturing any ending quote as well.  How do I make this option the "fallback" option, if the other tests don't work?

Here is one variation I tried in the Regex pattern:

```
        string pattern = @"^\s*(?<BeginQuote>"")?" +
            @"(?<BodyPattern>.+((\.(?=""?\s*$))|(?=""\s*$)|($)))" +
            @"(?<EndQuote>""(?=\s*$))?";
```

This pattern, however, always defaults to the end of string alternative:

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote, period and end quote."
Ending Quotation Mark:  False

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote and period.
Ending Quotation Mark:  False

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote and end quote"
Ending Quotation Mark:  False

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote only
Ending Quotation Mark:  False

I also tried putting the end of string alternative as the first choice (same output; and tried to make that expression "lazy" (but the few attempts I made using "??" yielded the same output).  I also tried various groupings of the alternatives (probably not all possibilities, though), with the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` quantifier is being greedy, use `+?` instead. This should do the trick.

```
string test = @"""This has a begin quote, period and end quote.""" + "\n" +
              @"""This has a begin quote and period." + "\n" +
              @"""This has a begin quote and end quote""" + "\n" +
              @"""This has a begin quote only";

Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?m)^\s*(?<BeginQuote>"")?(?<BodyPattern>.+?(?:\.|(?=""|$)))(?<EndQuote>"")?");

foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(test)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Beginning Quotation Mark: {0}", m.Groups["BeginQuote"].Success);
   Console.WriteLine("BodyPattern: {0}", m.Groups["BodyPattern"]);
   Console.WriteLine("Ending Quotation Mark: {0}", m.Groups["EndQuote"].Success);
   Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
}
```

Output

```
Beginning Quotation Mark: True
BodyPattern: This has a begin quote, period and end quote.
Ending Quotation Mark: True
--------------------------
Beginning Quotation Mark: True
BodyPattern: This has a begin quote and period.
Ending Quotation Mark: False
--------------------------
Beginning Quotation Mark: True
BodyPattern: This has a begin quote and end quote
Ending Quotation Mark: True
--------------------------
Beginning Quotation Mark: True
BodyPattern: This has a begin quote only
Ending Quotation Mark: False
--------------------------
```

Comment: Adding the lazy quantifier helped, but with the restructuring of the Regex logic, it fails if you add interior quotes.  I got my original code to work by just adding the "?" after the ".+" at the beginning.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am unable to upvote yet.  Need to add an optional ? after BeginningQuotationMark.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice troubleshooting, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I marked hwnd's answer as correct, for giving me the clue to how to use the lazy quantifier.  However, I used my code instead, since that Regex fails whenever you add interior quotes to the text or add extra whitespace.    I modified my test text and made it a bit more human-readable.  Here is what I ended up using:

```
        string test = "\"This has a begin quote, \"period\" and end quote.\t  \"\n  " +
                      "\"This has a begin quote and period.\n" +
                      "This has no begin quote but an end quote\"\n" +
                      "\"This has a \"begin\" quote only   \n" ;

        string pattern = @"^\s*(?<BeginQuote>"")?" +
            @"(?<BodyPattern>.+?((\.(?=""?\s*$))|(?=""\s*$)|($)))" +
            @"(?<EndQuote>""(?=\s*$))?";

        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(test);
```

Output:
Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote, "period" and end quote.
Ending Quotation Mark:  True

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a begin quote and period.
Ending Quotation Mark:  False

Beginning Quotation Mark:  False
BodyPattern:  This has no begin quote but an end quote
Ending Quotation Mark:  True

Beginning Quotation Mark:  True
BodyPattern:  This has a "begin" quote only
Ending Quotation Mark:  False